# import.io json API: get the list of columns, with subfields

Tags: import.io

I'm using the import.io API and have noticed that some field types return several columns in the generated json. For instance a field foo of type `Money` will return three columns: `foo`, `foo/_currency` and `foo/_source`.

Is there a reference somewhere? I found some documentation here http://blog.import.io/post/11-columns-of-importio through an incomplete example:

```
{
  "whole_number_field": 123,
  "whole_number_field/_source": "123",

  "language_field": "ben",
  "language_field/_source": "bn",

  "country_field": "CHN",
  "country_field/_source": "China",

  "boolean_field": false,
  "boolean_field/_source": "false",

  "currency_field/_currency": "GBP",
  "currency_field/_source": "£123.45",

  "link_field": "http://chris-alexander.co.uk",
  "link_field/_text": "Blog",
  "link_field/_title": "linktitle",

  "datetime_field": 611368440000,
  "datetime_field/_source": "17/05/89 12:34",
  "datetime_field/_utc": "Wed May 17 00:34:00 GMT 1989",

  "image_field": "http://io.chris-alexander.co.uk/gif2.gif", 
  "image_field/_alt": "imgalt",
  "image_field/_title": "imgtitle",
  "image_field/_source": "gif2.gif"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns are documented in the API docs:
http://api.docs.import.io/

For example, for currency, the columns are:

- myvar    <== Extracted value
- myvar/_currency    <== ISO currency code
- myvar/_source    <== Original value

The ISO currency code is returned as myvar/_currency, the numeric value in myvar

Answer (score 0):

I established this through several tests, I'd like to know if I'm missing something:

`{
    'DATE': ['_source', '_utc'],
      # please tell me if you have an example of an import.io API with a date!
    'BOOLEAN': ['_source'],
    'LANG': ['_source'],
    'COUNTRY': ['_source'],
    'HTML':[],
    'STRING':[],
    'URL': ['_text', '_source', '_title'],
    'IMAGE': ['_alt', '_title', '_source'],
    'DOUBLE': ['_source'],
    'CURRENCY': ['_currency', '_source'],
}`